# T-SQL Calculate the max value from an Alpha Numeric key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a customers table which has an Alphanumeric key consisting of 5 letters and 3 numbers.

I'm trying to calculate the next 3 digit number in sequence for each 5 letters for example:

**Example Key**

```
ALPHA001
ALPHA002
NUMBE001
NUMBE002
NUMBE003
PREST001
PREST002
PREST003
PREST004
PREST005
```

From the list of keys above i'd like to return the maximum of each unique 5 letter key. i.e.

**Returned Values**

```
ALPHA002
NUMBE003
PREST005
```

Comment: Use SEQUENCE objects instead of trying to parse and increment strings. Or *split* such keys into `category` and `ID` fields. Such "smart" keys are a big design problem

Comment: Another option is to create a 'Number Series' structure akin to many ERP systems (See Microsoft Business Central/NAV), so you define the number series' in a separate table and use that to record the 'last used' number in each valid range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by left(col, patindex('%[0-9]%', col)) order by col desc);
```

If the letters are fixed then just use `left()` :

```
order by row_number() over (partition by left(col, 5) order by col desc);
```

Comment: I really appreciate this approach with `WITH TIES` and `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER()` - until I compared the execution plans. The problem is, that the sorting is done twice. Quite a draw-back with larger sets...

Comment: People use it because it looks cool. If you want ties, use RANK.

Answer (score 4):

First of all: Do not store more than one value within one column. should store the key and the running number in separate columns and combine them just for display purpose...

Try this

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourKey VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
 ('ALPHA001')
,('ALPHA002')
,('NUMBE001')
,('NUMBE002')
,('NUMBE003')
,('PREST001')
,('PREST002')
,('PREST003')
,('PREST004')
,('PREST005');

WITH cte AS
(
SELECT *
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(YourKey,5) ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(YourKey,3) AS INT) DESC) AS PartitionedRowNumber 
FROM @mockupTable
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE PartitionedRowNumber =1;
```

The result

```
ID  Key
2   ALPHA002
5   NUMBE003
10  PREST005
```

Comment: Works a treat thanks. I agree with storing this as two separate values but this is a table from an old legacy system which still requires to be stored as an Alphanumeric.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to calculate the next 3 digit number in sequence for each 5
>   letters

This should do it:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(k, 5), FORMAT(MAX(RIGHT(k, 3)) + 1, '000'))
FROM (VALUES
    ('ALPHA001'),
    ('ALPHA002'),
    ('NUMBE001'),
    ('NUMBE002'),
    ('NUMBE003'),
    ('PREST001'),
    ('PREST002'),
    ('PREST003'),
    ('PREST004'),
    ('PREST005')
) tests(k)
GROUP BY LEFT(k, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `GROUP BY` and `MAX`:

```
SELECT  KeyPrefix = LEFT(ExampleKey, 5),
        NextKey = CONCAT(LEFT(ExampleKey, 5), 
                        RIGHT(CONCAT('000', MAX(CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(ExampleKey, 3))) + 1), 3))
FROM    (VALUES
            ('ALPHA001'), ('ALPHA002'), ('NUMBE001'), ('NUMBE002'), ('NUMBE003'), 
            ('PREST001'), ('PREST002'), ('PREST003'), ('PREST004'), ('PREST005')
        ) t (ExampleKey)
GROUP BY LEFT(ExampleKey, 5);
```

The key operations being:

1. Get number part of key: `RIGHT(ExampleKey, 3)`
2. Convert this to an integer: `CONVERT(INT, <output from 1>)`
3. Find the max for the key type and add 1:  `MAX(<output from 2>) + 1`
4. Pad this with zeros: `RIGHT(CONCAT('000', MAX(<output from 3>), 3)`
5. Concatenate withthe original prefix: `CONCAT(LEFT(ExampleKey, 5), <output from 4>)`

I would however highly recommed storing this in two columns, and use a computed column to combine then:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T
(
    KeyPrefix CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    KeySequence INT NOT NULL,
    TKey AS CONCAT(KeyPrefix, RIGHT(CONCAT('000', KeySequence), 3))
);
```

Then your query becomes much simpler:

```
SELECT  KeyPrefix, 
        KeySequence = MAX(KeySequence) + 1,
        TKey = CONCAT(KeyPrefix, RIGHT(CONCAT('000', MAX(KeySequence) + 1), 3))
FROM    (VALUES
            ('ALPHA', 1), ('ALPHA', 2), ('NUMBE', 1), ('NUMBE', 2), ('NUMBE', 3), 
            ('PREST', 1), ('PREST', 2), ('PREST', 3), ('PREST', 4), ('PREST', 5)
        ) t (KeyPrefix, KeySequence)
GROUP BY KeyPrefix;
```

Although worth noting that you would never actually need to reconstruct the key as I have done above in the column `TKey`, you just need the max keysequence.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query.

```
        GO
        ;WITH cte AS
        (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(YourKey,patindex('%[0-9]%', YourKey)) ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(YourKey,patindex('%[A-Z]%', YourKey)) AS INT) DESC) AS rr , YourKey FROM @mockupTable
        )
        SELECT YourKey FROM cte WHERE rr =1;

        GO
```